# How to make a dictionary that for key is word in English and for value a word in Greek (utf-8) , i'm getting a KeyError when i try to get the value

Tags: python, dictionary, utf-8

I'm trying to illustrate a translation dictionary that:

- when a word is given in English i return the meaning in Greek (utf-8)

  ```
  #Possible Content Of File:
  #"Hello,Γεια\n" 
  #"Car,Αμαξι\n"

  with codecs.open("dict.txt",'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
      lines= f.read()  #contains all the lines of the file

  word=raw_input("Word To Find\n")
  flag=0
  temp=""
  temp2=""
  dictionary={}
  #here is an algorithm i came up with, to seperate the string and get on temp the key
  #and on temp2 the value , then i add them on the dictionary
  for i in range(0,len(lines)):
      if flag==0:
          temp+=lines[i]
      if lines[i]==',':
          flag=1
          continue
      if lines[i]=='\n':
          flag=0
          dictionary.update({temp:temp2}) #adding the key and the value
          #(the value is in utf-8)
          temp=""
          temp2=""
      if flag==1:
          temp2+=lines[i]

  #print(dictionary.keys())  # [u'Hello,',u'Car,']
  #print(dictionary.get(word)) returns None
  print(dictionary[word])# KeyError
  ```

> Note: The file contains this kind of strings: "Hello,Γεια\n" and  "Car,Αμαξι\n"
>
> Error: print(dictionary[word]) throws a KeyError
>
> This is Python 2.7

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Step 1 of debugging: `print(dictionary.keys())`. Debugging complete. Step 1 of fixing the code: `dic_file= open('dict.txt'); dictionary= {e:g.strip() for e,g in (line.split(',') for line in dic_file)}`.

Comment: i'm getting the same content 11 times if i print the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of the question needs two loops. The outer loop goes through the lines, the inner loop through the characters of the current line, e.g.:

```
for line in lines:
    for i in range(0, len(line)):
        # Then using line[i] instead of lines[i]
```

Also, `read()` gets the whole contents, `readlines()` is the correct function.

The following implementation uses `split(',')` to separate the words in a line.
Also, the dictionary can be updated by a simple `dictionary[key] = value`.
    import codecs

```
with codecs.open("dict.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

word=raw_input("Word To Find\n")
dictionary={}
for line in lines:
    if ',' in line:
        key, value = line.split(',')
        dictionary[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    else:
        print('Cannot parse line: ' + line)

if word in dictionary:
    print(dictionary[word])
else:
    print('Error: Translation not found.')
```

The previous implementation assumes that the value is free from commas.
The following version allows commas in values:

```
for line in lines:
    comma_index = line.index(',')
    if comma_index >= 0:
        key = line[0:comma_index]
        value = line[comma_index + 1:]
        dictionary[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    else:
        print('Cannot parse line: ' + line)
```

Comment: OP named the variable "lines", but it's actually not a list of lines; it's a string containing the entire contents of the file. So no, this is not the problem.

Comment: Why don't you iterate through line itself: `for c in line:` ?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I would not iterate through the characters at all if not needed. The updated answer uses a simple `split(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your splitting algorithm is a bit buggy, and as there is built in support to do the same task in python, why do you reinvent the wheel?

```
import io
with io.open("test.txt",'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
        list_of_lines= f.read().splitlines()  #contains all the lines of the file in a list


dictionary={}

for line in list_of_lines:
    eng, greek = line.split(',')  # split(',') will split the string by ',' and make a list out of it
    dictionary[eng] = greek

print(dictionary['Hello'])
```

Comment: for some reason im getting a TypeError: 'encoding' is invalid keyword arguement for this function
Line: with open("dict.txt",'r',encoding='utf8') as f:

Comment: That's because you are using python2, this is a solution for python3. Let me post the fix in a moment.

Comment: @Phill, the answer is updated and will work in python2.